# How to repeat the table on each page of the PDF with iText7?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

*iText7 v8.0.1*

I have a separate tables for header and footer, and I would like this tables to be repeated on every page, on top and bottom respectively.

The problem is that there is no any out of the box method that can give me this feature.

**What I have tried:**
Official documentation example:

```
// header row:
            table.AddHeaderCell("Key");
            table.AddHeaderCell("Value");
            table.SetSkipFirstHeader(true);

            // many data rows:
            for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
            {
                table.AddCell("key: " + i);
                table.AddCell("value: " + i);
            }
```

**What I see with this code:**
My content table which goes after header table is continued, and in the next page I dont see my header table.

The problem with this code, is that it is using header cell in one global table. Which means that I must have all of my tables combined into one table, which is not my case.